# Is this slogan proper English?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-requests

We are a group of web developers, creating our online presence ...
We chose this slogan,

> "Web passionate young powers at your service"

- Is this proper English?
- Does this hold any "contempt" on our side when using "at your service" in western traditions?
- Any suggestion for a similar meaning one?

Comment: I wouldn't show any contempt if I saw that. The only thing I would have problems with, is whether or not the "young" was a noun or an adjective. Are you "web passionate young" who power for our service, or "young powers" who are web passionate, waiting on us?

Comment: it's young powers.

Comment: This slogan is word salad. There's simply no way to figure out how the words relate to each other.

Comment: This is getting way outside the scope of EL&U, but I thought I should say: your slogan has things backwards. You concentrate on the Features you possess. You should concentrate on the Benefits you can deliver. (See http://businesscoaching.typepad.com/the_business_coaching_blo/2009/08/features-advantages-benefits-make-your-selling-fab.html to learn more.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your slogan needs a lot of work.  I've read through it half a dozen times, and can't figure out what you're trying to say.  There are so many problems, I hardly know where to begin (sorry to be so blunt, but, I'm guessing you're soliciting candid feedback, so I may as well do my best to provide that).

Are you trying to say that you are a young company, passionate about what you do, and eager to serve its customers?  If that's what you're saying, you've put the words together in the wrong order.  Something like "*Passionate young web developers at your service*" would be much better.

That said, I still think it needs a lot of work.  Here's why:

1) *Young* is a poor word choice.  Sure, "young" can imply youthful and energetic, but it also conveys inexperience.  I would be very hesitant to business with a company whose slogan emphasizes a lack of seasoned leadership.

2) "*At your service*" is something that a concierge might say at a hotel, or a waiter might say in a restaurant, but it doesn't seem to fit well with a web development company.

3) What do you mean by *powers*?  It's very hard to determine what you are alluding to.  The power of the web?  The power of your developers?  The power of your company?

4) *Passionate* may not be a good word selection, either.  One online dictionary lists [three meanings](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/passionate) for this word.  One is *enthusiastic*, which is fine, but the other two meanings are "*easily aroused to anger*," and "*swayed by sexual desire*".  I don't think either of those are what you're trying to say!

I'll take a stab at offering an improved slogan: ***Dedicated to harnessing the power of the web for you***.

*Dedicated* is a word I'd use instead of *passionate*; "*for you*" can convey "*at your service*" without sounding so trite.  *Harness* implies that you are working toward letting your customers get all they can from the Internet.

Comment: Wow , this was just a great analysis.. This is what I call , A SUPERIOR ANSWER !

Comment: Might use your suggested slogan after the team meets.

Answer (score 1):

> Web passionate young powers at your service

There’s nothing wrong with *at your service*, but *Web passionate young powers* is an ugly [crash blossom](http://www.crashblossoms.com/about). Is *young* a noun or an adjective?  Is *powers* a verb or a noun?

I think you’re trying to squeeze too much into your slogan. How about just:

> The web, at your service

Comment: Lol , I felt the same when I read it again and again trying to figure out what makes it un natural.

Comment: I like this version. Sounds like a giant genie coming to you and say in a respectful baritone...**The WEB...is at your service**!

Answer (score 0):

Considering my comment above, I thought maybe I might put it into an answer.

I'm assuming that you are meaning "young powers" that are 'web passionate' in your slogan. How about switching the position of "young"?

> Young web passionate powers at your service

Or maybe try another word from "powers":

> Web passionate young guns at your service.
>   Web-passionate young professionals at your service.

Putting the hyphen there may also help in reading.

Overall, your slogan is pretty good. It's short, punchy, and will work well.

Comment: Well ... comparing your answer to mine, I think there’s some room for debate.  :-)

Comment: @Pitarou, the OP clarified that "young" was an adjective. And yes, there is quite a difference between yours and mine:)

Comment: Nice suggestions.. I like "Web passionate young guns at your service" , sounds better than powers.

Comment: @Bidella I’m quite capable of parsing that sentence.  My point is that it’s not easy to parse.  A sentence that is hard to parse, fails.  A *slogan* that is hard to parse fails utterly.  And ... well ... put it this way, all the memorable corporate slogans I can think of (and if it’s not memorable, it fails) are no more than four words long.

Comment: @Pitarou, I get you now. And yes, I agree with you. A slogan shouldn't be hard to parse at all.